# Get Value Of API Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using a service with an API key and I want to print my balance.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

r = session.post('https://api.anycaptcha.com/getBalance', data = {'clientKey': API})
```

Everything works. When I do `print(r.text)` the following dictionary gets print:

`{"errorId":0,"errorCode":"SUCCESS","balance":20.0}`

However, I just want to get the value of "balance" (20.0). But I couldn't figure out how.

What I tried:

```
print(r.text['balance'])
# Output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(r.text['balance'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Note that `r.text` is, as the name suggests, _text_ (a string), not a dictionary

Comment: as @ForceBru mentioned - text is a string. So you need to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, as r.text is a string with your dict

```
import json
d = json.loads(r.text)

#Now you can access dict
d["balance"]
```